# Illustrator: wrap a rounded rectangle around a point

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

I am wondering how to achieve this effect:

[image]

Basically what I'm trying to do is create rounded rectangles and wrap them around a center point.

I have tried to create rounded rectangles and apply a warp effect, but I had no success.

Is there a corresponding distort effect?

Comment: Yes but it may be easier to use a brush instead.

Comment: @Vincent I have tried to create rounded rectangles and apply a warp effect, but I had no success. joojaa How is this effects possible with brushes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would utilize Strokes for this. Set a dashed Stroke on a circle with Round Caps then tweak it to the appearance you'd like. Modify the dash/gaps for sizing and layer a bunch of circles if needed.

[image: dashed Stroke with Round Caps]

The illustration in your example doesn't have a straight-on perspective, so for that you'd need to tweak the circles first. Illustrator has [lots of tools](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/scaling-shearing-distorting-objects.html) to help you achieve the perspective, but ultimately you can still use a dashed stroke for the effect. I distorted three circles in this example (two larger ones with different Dash settings):

[image: Windmill example]